# Flutter: Send form-data for Http GET request

Tags: flutter, api

I need to make a GET request to an API from my Flutter app which request body as form-data.

I tested the API with JSON request body in Postman and it seems to be working fine.

[image]

Comment: There's no such thing as form data on a GET. Those have to be sent as query parameters - see https://www.semrush.com/blog/url-parameters/ The Uri named constructor allows you to pass them in as a map https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/Uri/Uri.https.html

Comment: In your screen shot you are *not* using a JSON request body.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GET request method there can be two ways to to pass parameters as **Query Paremeters** or **Path Paremeters**

Your request dart code would be like

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future getPatientAppointments() async {
    String appointmentUrl = "$url/api/PatientAppointments/GetMyPatientAppointmentAsDoctor";
    String startDate = "01-05-2021";
    String endDate = "01-05-2021";
    var _response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse("$appointmentUrl?startDate=$startDate&endDate=$endDate"),
    );
    print(_response.body);
}
```